# Ритм стихотворный

Tags: литература

Я прочитал одну интересную теоретическую статью про стихотворный ритм. После прочтения текста я задался вопросом: "А как можно обозначить у стихотворения ритм?" Если можно - с примерами.

Answer (score 4):

Стихотворный ритм можно обозначить определённым количеством слогов в строчке, можно определённым количеством ударений, а можно использовать и тот и другой способ.

Первый способ называется силлабическим (от греческого syllabia - слог)  стихосложением, второй - тоническим (от греческого ton - ударение), а третий, соответственно, силлабо-тоническим. Сами эти способы имеют ещё кучу разделений, и вариаций, которых я тут касаться не буду в виду их массивности, если интересно в интернете много соответствующих справочников и литературы.

**Пример силлабического стиха Антиоха Кантемира:**

*Уме недозрелый, плод недолгой науки!

Покойся, не понуждай к перу мои руки:

Не писав летящи дни века проводити

Можно, и славу достать, хоть творцом не слыти.

Ведут к ней нетрудные в наш век пути многи,

На которых смелые не запнутся ноги.*

**Пример силлабо-тонического стиха Александра Пушкина:**

*Я вас любил: любовь еще, быть может,

В душе моей угасла не совсем;

Но пусть она вас больше не тревожит;

Я не хочу печалить вас ничем.

Я вас любил безмолвно, безнадежно,

То робостью, то ревностью томим;

Я вас любил так искренно, так нежно,

Как дай вам бог любимой быть другим.*

**Пример тонического стихотворения Владимра Маяковского:**

*Послушайте!

Ведь, если звезды зажигают —

значит — это кому-нибудь нужно?

Значит — кто-то хочет, чтобы они были?

Значит — кто-то называет эти плевочки жемчужиной?

И, надрываясь

в метелях полуденной пыли,

врывается к Богу,

боится, что опоздал,

плачет,

целует ему жилистую руку,

просит —

чтоб обязательно была звезда! —

клянется —

не перенесет эту беззвездную муку!

А после

ходит тревожный,

но спокойный наружно.

Говорит кому-то:

«Ведь теперь тебе ничего?

Не страшно?

Да?!»

Послушайте!

Ведь, если звезды

зажигают —

значит — это кому-нибудь нужно?

Значит — это необходимо,

чтобы каждый вечер

над крышами

загоралась хоть одна звезда?!*

Answer (score 2):

Можно то же самое объяснить проще...
Ритм в стихе образуется за счет ударных слогов тех слов, которые есть в стихе. Вообще говоря, ритм - это правильное чередование ударных и безударных слогов. Например, каждый первый слог - ударный, а каждый второй - безударный: "нИвы сжАты, рОщи гОлы". Или: каждый третий слог - ударный: "и, прервАв дальний пУть, ляжешь тЫ отдохнУть..."
Строго выдержанный ритм образует пять классических размеров: хорей и ямб (двухсложные) и дактиль, амфибрахий, анапест (трехсложные). Они отличаются расположением ударного слога (первый, второй...) и количеством безударных между ударными. Так, хорей - размер, где первый слог ударный, второй безударный (то же "нивы сжаты, рощи голы"). Ямб - наоборот, двухсложный размер, где первый слог безударный, второй ударный. "судьбА онЕгинА хранИла". В слове "Онегина" ударное "а" образуется за счет икта - ритмического ударения.
Амфибрахий - трехсложный размер. В нем ударный слог посередине: "не вЕтер бушУет над бОром".
Дактиль - тоже трехсложный размер, только там ударный слог первый: "кАк хорошО ты, о мОре ночнОе".
И, наконец, анапест - трехсложный размер с последним ударным словом. "принимАю тебЯ! принимАю и привЕтствую звОном щитА!".
Если вы поэт, то не вредно знать, что трехсложные размеры легче выдерживать (а не выдерживать нельзя, ритм - основа стиха). Но важен не только ритм, но и стопность - количество ударных слогов. Стопа - это ударный слог с прилегающими к нему безударными. В последнем примере стоп три. В примере из Есенина (нивы сжаты...) - четыре. Лишняя или недостающая стопа - это ритмическая грязь.

Answer (score 1):

В широком смысле ритмообразующие элементы:

1.Членение речи на стихотворные строки, т. е. стихи (строки часто не совпадают с законченными синтаксическими единицами).

2.Соразмерное количество слогов в строке(организация слогов неодинакова в стихотворных произведениях разных народов, разных времен и зависит от особенностей национального языка, его исторического развития).

3.Соразмерное количество ударений в строке. 
Равномерная повторяемость стоп в строке (стопа - ударный слог с примыкающим к нему безударным).

4.Рифма - созвучия концов стихов. Стихотворение без рифм - «белый стих».

5.Строфа - группа стихов, объединенных формальным признаком. (Онегинская строфа, сонет и т.д.)

6.Паузы - внутренние (цезура) и концевые (на конце строки).

В узком смысле единицей ритма считают метр - размер.Основных силлабо-тонических размеров пять.
 У каждого размера есть своя цифровая «формула»:

Хорей — это стих, где ударения должны падать на нечетные слоги. Значит, формула хорея —1, 3, 5, 7, 9... и т. д.
Сквозь туман кремнистый путь блестит...

Ямб — это стих, где ударения должны падать на четные слоги. Значит, формула ямба — 2, 4, 6, 8, 10... и т. д.
Конечно, царь: сильна твоя держава

Дактиль — это стих, где ударения должны падать на слоги: 1, 4, 7, 10... и т. д.
Солнце садится, и ветер утихнул летучий
1 2-» 3 4 -5 -67 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

Амфибрахий — это стих, где ударения должны падать на слоги 2, 5, 8, 11... и т. д.
В песчаных степях аравийской земли

Анапест — это стих, где ударения должны падать на слоги: 3, 6, 9, 12... и т. д.
Вот парадный подъезд. По торжественным дням...

Слоги не всегда бывают ударными.Встречается пиррихий — пропуск ударения на «положенном» ему месте,лишнее ударение - спондей. Если не подходит под эти формулы, это неклассический стих, его называют по-разному: и дольник, и логаэдический стих, акцентный, тонический и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Стихотворные размеры

Двусложные размеры
Хорей – двусложная стопа в русском стихосложении, в которой ударение падает первый слог.
_/ _

> Обла/ ком  во/ лнистым/
>   Пыль  вста/ ет  вда/ ли...
>   (А.А.Фет)

Ямб – двусложная стопа в русском стихосложении, в которой ударение падает второй (последний) слог.
_  _/

> По  до/ му  бро/ дит  при/ виде/ нье,
>   Весь день/  шаги/  над го/ловой/...
>   (Б.Л.Пастернак)

Трехсложные размеры
Дактиль (от греческого – палец) – трехсложная стопа в русском стихосложении, в которой ударение падает на первый из трех слогов.
 _/ _  _

Амфибрахий (от греческого – с двух сторон) – трехсложная стопа в русском стихосложении, в которой ударение падает на второй слог – ударный между двумя безударными.
_  _/ _

Анапест (от греческого – отраженный назад) – трехсложная стопа в русском стихосложении, в которой ударение падает на третий, последний слог.
_  _  _/

Как определять стихотворный размер?

1. Чтобы определить количество слогов в строке, подчеркнем все гласные буквы.
2. Произнесем строку нараспев и расставим ударения.
3. Теперь проверим, через какое количество слогов повторяется ударение: 
   а) если повторяется каждые 2 слога, это двусложный размер: хорей или ямб;
   б) если повторяется каждые 3 слога, это трехсложный размер: дактиль, амфибрахий или анапест.
4. Остается разделить слоги в строке на стопы (по два или три в каждой) и определить размер стихотворения.

Answer (score 1):

Хотел ограничится комментарием, да не уместился.

Давайте от печки.

> В поэзии под термином «ритм» понимают одно из следующего:
>
> - общая упорядоченность звукового строения стихотворной речи; частным случаем ритма в этом значении является метр;
> - реальное звуковое строение конкретной стихотворной строки в противоположность отвлеченной метрической схеме; в этом значении,
>     наоборот, ритм является частным случаем («ритмической формой»,
>     «вариацией», «модуляцией») метра и стихотворного размера.
>     (вики)

Полагаю, речь идет о первом значении, о стихотворном ритме, напрямую связанном с метром (размером).

Вас интересует именно ***как обозначить***? Всё, что сказано ниже, суть ответы на вопрос, что это такое, ритм, и какой он бывает. Это вам должно быть известно, коли вы статьи теоретические на эту тему читаете. А обозначения - либо выделить в строке гласные (или слоги), на которые падает ритмическое ударение (оно может отличаться от обычного,  фонетического), либо просто указать размер. Обычно этим никто не занимается без нужды, ритм и размер стиха понятен каждому, кто более или менее правильно ставит ударения, другое дело, что далеко не все знают их названия. Для обозначения же самих образцов таких ритморазмеров в русской силлаботонике применяются специальные обозначения.
/ - ударный слог
∪ (или —) - безударный.
Обычно этого достаточно.

Например.
Б**у**ря мгл**о**ю н**е**бо кр**о**ет
В**и**хри сн**е**жны**е** крут**я**.

или

**/**∪**/**∪**/**∪**/**∪
**/**∪**/**∪**∪**∪**/**
Это, как вы догадываетесь, хорей.
Обратите внимание, что во второй строке ударная (ритмически сильная) доля один раз попадает на фонетически безударный слог.

Это по поводу обозначений как таковых. 
А о самих ритмах можно говорить до бесконечности, если вопрос о них, надо бы как-то конкретизировать.